# Node.js, russian characters in the query are poorly decoded

Tags: node.js, utf-8, decode, utf-16

I'm use

`curl -Lk 'https://my-site.ru/?q=повар'`

and in nodejs server `req.url`

I see `?q=Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð¸ÑÐµÐ»Ñ`

Locale character encoding `UTF-8`. What need to for normally decode character?

Comment: What is your OS, and shell, from which you are doing `curl`? What is the code where you see `?q=Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð¸ÑÐµÐ»Ñ`?

Comment: @Amadan i'm use OS macOS Mojave version 10.14.2, shell Zsh version 5.5.1. Code server: Express version "^4.16.2"

`router.get('/', (req) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
});`

Comment: Can you also report what `locale` command gives you?

Comment: @Amadan 
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=`

Comment: @Amadan 
sorry, i lying, accidentally in the container looked. Here is such
`LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: Sorry, wasn't your locale after all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `curl` not sending the URL correctly. URL is supposed to be in URL encoding (where `повар` should be `%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80`) to be standards-compliant. To make `curl` send it in this format, you can do this (note that I have to use `-G` to force GET protocol, otherwise `--data-encode` will make it POST):

```
curl -GLk 'https://my-site.ru/' --data-encode 'q=повар'
```

Then `req.query.q` will be `"повар"`.

Your `curl` is sending it straight as UTF-8, which is non-standard in URLs. I'm getting `Ð¿Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ` (not what you stated). The first letter, `п`, becomes `D0 BF`, which Express doesn't decode as UTF-8, but takes each as its own character: 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH' (U+00D0) and 'INVERTED QUESTION MARK' (U+00BF) - i.e. `Ð¿`. It is possible to decode this; in Node, the easiest way would be with `utf8` package (`utf8.decode(req.query.q)`); however I would strongly suggest you just go with standards.

Note that when you type `https://my-site.ru/?q=повар` in your browser (as opposed to `curl`), your browser will actually correctly send `https://my-site.ru/?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80` instead.

Comment: Thx for answer. I know standard for decodeURI/encodeURI. But if i du it in php, that work normal and without encodeURI. I wondered why it didn't work in the nodejs